# How to write a Batch Script that searches for files based on list

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone assist me in writing a batch script that searches for file names and outputs the location of the files to a text file.  Example I have a file called list.txt located in a folder, C:\LocateFiles\list.txt.  Located in the list.txt file are about 25 file names that I wish to determine if they are anywhere on the C:\ drive. If it locates any of the file names identified in the file list.txt it will output the path of all files found to a single file in C:\LocatedFiles\results.txt.

A million thanks,
Johnny Mac

Comment: Are you aware that this process may take _a lot_ of time? Isn't there any way to limit the search to a few folders?

Comment: Sure! Not a problem! Virtually any of the batch regulars would be able to assist you. Just edit your question to include your effort at solving your problem (we won't laugh - none of us have a sense of humour) and we'll try to fix the problem. That way, we know you're not just trying to use SO as a free code-writing service. (clue: it's a one-liner...)

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%F IN (C:\LocateFiles\List.txt) DO DIR /s/p/b %%F.* >> C:\LocateFiles\finds.txt
```

Save that as **LocateFiles.cmd** and place it in whichever directory you wish to search, note that C:\ is very large and will take quite a while! *as in, forever, seriously, i really wouldnt, your call...*

the file **finds.txt** will have the entire path for any file that matches up to the file names listed in List.txt

Also note, this finds files of **any extension**, but the filename itself must match **exactly** to whats in **List.txt**

Answer (score 2):

The solution below search the files in the current directory *just once*, so it run faster.

```
@echo off
dir /S /B /A-D | findstr /I /G:C:\LocateFiles\list.txt > C:\LocatedFiles\results.txt
```

**EDIT**: *New method added*

The method below may run even faster. It is necessary to complete a timing test.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read file names from file list and assemble a long string with this format:
rem "filename1.ext*" "filename2.ext*" ...
set "fileList="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\LocateFiles\list.txt) do set fileList=!fileList! "%%a*"

rem Search the files from current directory downwards
(for /R %%a in (%fileList%) do echo %%a) > C:\LocatedFiles\results.txt
```